# How do margins work on floated elements and elements around them?

Tags: css

Looking at the bottom example [here](http://learnlayout.com/clear.html), if you give .after-box a `margin-top:5px` it doesn't make a difference as it'll stay in the same location. But if you give .box a `margin-bottom:5px` it'll move the .after-box down. Why is it that on floated elements, their margin matters but other elements around them don't?

Answer (score 1):

Hey margins don't move floated html elements, instead they push it away.
To give a fake margins on floated elements is to put the content inside another container then apply `padding`.

```
.outer {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}

.inner {
 //styles here..
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between moving vs pushing?

Comment: and my question was why giving a floated element margin will push others away, but giving others a margin will not push the floated element away